# HanaDecimal has not a serializable attribute

Tags: c#, hana

I am trying to use Dapper with Hana provider (HANA .Net Core 2.1 ADO.NET Provider, cf [Microsoft .NET Core Support](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.04/en-US/bd3548f9c00845849fe4d883148974d1.html) in SAP Library "SAP HANA Client Interface Programming Reference for SAP HANA Platform"). Everything is working fine with casual `DataReader` but there is a problem when I try to use some entity class that contains decimal type with Dapper:

```cs
public class SomeType 
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

var resultSet = hanaConnection.Query<SomeType>("some hana sql");
```

Unfortunately, the following exception is thrown:

> Type 'Sap.Data.Hana.HanaDecimal' in Assembly 'Sap.Data.Hana.Core.v2.1,
>   Version=2.4.151.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0326b8ea63db4bc4'
>   is not marked as serializable.

I have tried to create own type handler for `decimal`, no luck:

```
public class DecimalTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<decimal>
{
    public override decimal Parse(object value)
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(value);
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, decimal value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Mapper is not even called, so I suppose that error is thrown while fetching data from db.

Is there any workaround since I cannot add `Serializable` attribute to proprietary, source-closed assembly?

Comment: HanaDecimal is a structure : https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.03/en-US/d19627fd6d611014a0c6b44edb5557a6.html

Comment: @jdweng still - dapper detects it as not marked with `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: @pwas hi; primary Dapper author here; can I see the stack trace for that exception? I don't recall ever checking for, or caring about, `[Serializable]`; and indeed: `Find all "serializable", Subfolders, Find Results 1, Entire Solution, "*.*"
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 196`

Comment: As long as the property/class is public the serializer will work without the [Serializable].  The issue is the type is wrong.  It is not a decimal but a structure.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for hint. problem solved. It turned out that someone wrapped my code with serialization part (much much deeper) and I spotted that when saw stacktrace. Everything is working now when using TypeHandler I have put above.

Comment: @pwas k; removing the [tag:dapper] tag, then - since that doesn't seem to be related

Comment: @MarcGravell ok, seems to be reasonable thing.

Comment: @pwas Please add "problem solved..." as an [answer and mark it as Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marc Gravell who guided me to peek a stack trace it turned out that serialization was added by someone else and it has nothing with dapper.

Everyting is working using `DecimalTypeHandler` presented inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add type handler before query:

```
 SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new DecimalTypeHandler ());
 var resultSet = hanaConnection.Query<SomeType>("some hana sql");
```

Comment: I have added it as stated in question - no luck.

Comment: please look at updated answer; try redefine handler

Comment: still not working. Type handler is not even called - the exception is thrown frist.